# How to add one arraylist to other arraylist in android?

Tags: android

I have created 3 arraylists and stored data in it. I need to pass one single arraydata to other page and so I have added my individual arrays to the main array. But when I added one array to other the data is not being aded to that array. Here is my code:

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stringList1=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stringList3; 

stringList1 = Mypage.stringList1;

 ArrayList<String> optionlist = new ArrayList<String>();
stringList3 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();stringList3 = dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDBList(query2, null); 
 for (int i = 0; i < stringList3.size(); i++) {
    optionlist = stringList3.get(i);
    System.out.print("option list size");
    System.out.print(optionlist.size());
    stringList1.add(optionlist);
    System.out.println("total stringlist1"+stringList1.get(0));
```

I am getting the stringList1 array values from Mypage and accessing that in new page. In the new page I am trying to add the optionlist array to stringList1 by giving stringList1.add(optionlist) but the data is not adding. Where I went wrong? Please help me regarding this... Thanks in Advance

Comment: No iteration required. Read this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8666707/2707485

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After seeing your code I can guess that you have problem that elements of arrayList is not copy in another arrayList.If this is your issue then change your code like below

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stringList1=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stringList3; 

stringList1 = Mypage.stringList1;

ArrayList<String> optionlist;
stringList3 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
stringList3 = dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDBList(query2, null); 

 for (int i = 0; i < stringList3.size(); i++) {
    optionlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    optionlist = stringList3.get(i);
    System.out.print("option list size");
    System.out.print(optionlist.size());
    stringList1.add(optionlist);
    System.out.println("total stringlist1"+stringList1.get(0));
 }
```

Answer (score 15):

Use `addAll()` It appends all of the elements in the specified ArrayList to the end of this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified Collection's Iterator.

use `stringList1.addAll(optionlist);` instead of `stringList1.add(optionlist);`

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems that you are initializing your

```
ArrayList<String> optionlist;
```

only once that is outside the loop. So, in that case only the first `ArrayList` gets stored. So, initialized the `ArrayList<String> optionlist` inside the loop.

```
ArrayList<String> optionlist;

for (int i = 0; i < stringList3.size(); i++) {
    optionlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    optionlist = stringList3.get(i);
    stringList1.add(optionlist);
 }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response..I took a list but even then the same problem..plz help me

Comment: I can't get you what you are trying to do actually, so please can you explain more.

Comment: I am getting values from stringlist1 from page1 to page2 using stringlist1 = page1.stringlist1. Now I need to add my optionlist array which is in page2 to stringList1 arraylist. But the data is not adding to stringlist1.What is the mistake I am doing?

Comment: hmmm the problem is you are only initializing your ArrayList only once outside the loop check my edited answer.