# How to store all ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> values into ArrayList<String>?

Tags: java, android

I am having issue to store all values of `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` into `ArrayList<String>`. Here `stylistIDArray` and `durationArray` are array of array. I want to store all their values in `stylistId` and `duration` respectively. The `stylistid` and `duration` are array of string.

Here's my attempt, but it stores only the last item of each array of array.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stylistIDArray;
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> durationArray;
stylistIDArray = differentGenderServicesAdapter.getSelectedStylistIdArray();                
durationArray = differentGenderServicesAdapter.getSelectedDurArray();

ArrayList<String>stylistId = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String>duration = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0; i<stylistIDArray.size(); i++) {
    stylistId = stylistIDArray.get(i);
    duration = durationArray.get(i);
}
```

Note : I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666678/how-to-add-one-arraylist-to-other-arraylist-in-android), but doesn't work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add one arraylist to other arraylist in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666678/how-to-add-one-arraylist-to-other-arraylist-in-android)

Comment: its not working

Comment: i tried with the code in that link

Comment: In that case you should add that link in to your question.. and mentioned that answer is not working for you

Comment: i tried with the link which you had given its not working for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666678/how-to-add-one-arraylist-to-other-arraylist-in-android

Comment: Could you provide the type of all var ? (`stylistIDArray`, `durationArray`)

Comment: ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stylistIDArray=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> durationArray=new ArrayList<>();

Comment: @Deepa please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50874726/edit) your question instead of completing it in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be generic, First let be an list of list of objects

```
List<List<Object>> listOfList;
```

That you want to put into a list of object

```
List<Object> result;
```

*Note the result list will contain every object contain is the input list. This transformation will loose the information of which object was in which list.*

You have to loop through the `listOfList`. At each loop you obtain a list of object (`List<Object> listOfObject`). Then loop through these lists to obtain every object (`Object o`). Then add these object to the result list (`result.add(o)`).

```
for(List<Object> listOfObject : listOfList) {
    for(Object o : listOfObject) {
        result.add(o);
    }
}
```

---

In your case, the problem is that you use affectation instead of `add()`. At every loop this replaces the value by the new one. So at the end you have stored only the last item of each list.

```
stylistId=stylistIDArray.get(i); //This replace the existing stylistId
```

Instead try something like

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stylistIDArray;
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> durationArray;
stylistIDArray = differentGenderServicesAdapter.getSelectedStylistIdArray();
durationArray = differentGenderServicesAdapter.getSelectedDurArray();

ArrayList<String> stylistId = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> duration = new ArrayList<>();

for(ArrayList<String> l : stylistIDArray) {
    for(String s : l) {
        stylistId.add(s);
    }
}
for(ArrayList<String> l : durationArray ) {
    for(String s : l) {
        duration.add(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You doing wrong operation with `arraylist`, in loop you are getting data from  `stylistIDArray` and assign to `aryalist`, not inserting in list, have look this

```
stylistIDArray=differentGenderServicesAdapter.getSelectedStylistIdArray();
                        durationArray=differentGenderServicesAdapter.getSelectedDurArray();

                        ArrayList<String>stylistId=new ArrayList<>();
                        ArrayList<String>duration=new ArrayList<>();

                       for(int i=0; i<stylistIDArray.size(); i++) {
                           stylistId.add(stylistIDArray.get(i));
                           duration.add(durationArray.get(i));
                       }
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: If i follow this it asking me to change stylistid array into arrayofarray list

Comment: i want to store it in arraylist not in arrayofarray list

Comment: of-course it will store in arraylist you have to typecast.

Comment: k i will try it